# Can i decide how much memory to allocate in LSF queue

Tags: unix, memory, resources, jobs, lsf

Is there any option to decide how much memory I can allocate in LSF?

I tried

> bsub -R "rusage[mem=10000]" sleep 1000s

But when i checked resource using "bjobs -l "
I get this:

```
Job <203180>, User <xxxxx>, Project <default>, Status <RUN>, Queue <medium>,
                     Job Priority <50>, Command <sleep 1000s>
Thu Apr 12 09:49:56: Submitted from host <xxxx>, CWD <xx>, Requested Resources <rusa
                     ge[mem=10000]>;
Thu Apr 12 09:49:58: Started on <xxxx>, Execution Home <xxxx>, E
                     xecution CWD <xxxxx>;
Thu Apr 12 09:49:58: Resource usage collected.
                     MEM: 3 Mbytes;  SWAP: 16 Mbytes;  NTHREAD: 1
                     PGID: 28231;  PIDs: 28231
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: not a programming question. Voting to move to serverfault.com. Or you can use the flag link to ask a moderator to move it for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bsub -R "rusage[mem=10000]": will initially reserve 10000 MBytes of memory.

Whereas:

"MEM: 3 Mbytes" is the total resident memory usage of all currently running processes in your job.
"SWAP: 16 Mbytes" is the total virtual memory usage of all currently running processes in your job.

The values "3 Mbytes" and "16 Mbytes" may change during the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In my system we use -M, say bsub -M 1 to request 1 G of memory limit, the job is killed if it goes above that limit.